# Updating clientCache in web config not changing expires header

Tags: caching, static-content

I have a site running on iis7.5 where, through Firebug, I can see that my static content (css, js and images) have an expiration in their header consistently set to one day in the future. I find no where this is set, but I just came on recently to the project.

I want to make the expiration further in the future, so added a section in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="100.00:00:00" />
   </staticContent> 
</system.webServer>
```

After restarting the site, this had no affect on the expiration date of these items.

My question is, what can override the clientCache setting, imposing a different expiration date?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I just set up a simple site with a single image and the configuration you indicated above, and I get a Cache-Control: max-age=8640000 header back when using curl. 8640000 seconds is 100 days, so your configuration looks correct.

Comment: Yes, I don't think its the configuration, I think something is overriding it somewhere....I'm just not sure where to look. Thanks.